# Is it better to use Cookies when you have a lot of people logging into your site?

Tags: cookies

The question says it all, is it better to use cookies instead of sessions because, since sessions are variables stored in the server, it might cause the server to crash?

Comment: You are free to choose your session storage. It might be a file system or memcache and even database. It should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing Cookies and Session vars (and I assume you are referring to ASP.NET etc). Cookies are stored on the Client PC's and which can be used to track and store useful "stuff" about your web site visitor, like last time they visited, or default selections etc.

Session vars are used server side to handle program flow between page post backs and page loads (use ViewState vars for retaining data between postbacks on the same page / Session vars if you link from page to page). Session vars do take memory to manage and are lost if IIS decides to refresh its apps pool. Session vars should not make your "server crash".

So the answer your question:

- use cookies to track user info
- use session vars to manage program flow - use them sparingly